# C# Possibility to change password one time per day

Tags: c#, authentication, passwords

I have to write a code to change a password

```
if (txtNewPassword.Text == txtConfirmPassword.Text)
{
    mSQL = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE userName = '" + txtUserName.Text + "' AND password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
    mDT_Save = mDBHelper.GetTable(mSQL);
    if (mDT_Save.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mDT_Save.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            mSQL = "UPDATE User SET password = '" + txtConfirmPassword.Text + "' WHERE userName = '" + Convert.ToString(mDT_Save.Rows[i]["userName"]) + "'";
            mDBHelper.ExecuteSQLNonQuery(mSQL);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Password Changed Successfully");
        txtPassword.Text = txtConfirmPassword.Text;
        return;
   }
   else
   {
        MessageBox.Show("User Not Found");
        return;
   }
}
```

In this way the user can change his password everytime he wants, but I want that the user can change his password just one time per day. How can I write this condition?

Comment: You could store the last password changed `DateTime` in the database and check this before updating the password. Also consider to hash your password before storing it. You should never ever store a password in plaintext!

Comment: You can save in DB the last time the user changed his password, and use that value for verify if the user can change his password.

Comment: Try a new password of `'; -- ` and then look at using SqlParameter and parameterized queries. Expected result: all users in the database have their passwords set to a blank string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new column to the user table, where you store a DateTime value with the last DateTime chaging the password.

You can get the actual DateTime with this function:

```
DateTime.Now
```

Now if you want to check  if 24 hours has been passed since the last password change do it like this:

```
private bool CanChangePassword()
{
    DateTime dt = //value from database (last password change);

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    if (dt == DateTime.MinValue || now > dt.AddHours(24))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `DateTime changedpassworddate = DateTime.now();` to get the current date and put it in a variable.

store this variable in your database.

next time the user enters his password you can get the DateTime from the database compare it with the current DateTime like this:

```
if(DateTime.now() < changedpassworddate.AddDays(1))
{your abort code}
else
{your continue code}
```

using the add days method means the user can only change his password once every 24 hours. so changing it at 23:59 and then changing it at 0:01 won't work.